# How to properly include a var when creating a table in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

What's the proper way to include a var in the table name of my sql query? I've tried

```
CREATE TABLE `'$username'_table`
```

but that just creates

```
'username'_table
```

ive tried sever other combinations but i just keep getting either something with a space or quotes, i just want to to show up as simply

```
username_table






function makeUserTable($username)
           {
           return mysql_query("

    CREATE TABLE `'$username'_table` (
      `userid_id` bigint(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `userid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`userid_id`)
    )

    ");
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{}`:

```
`{$username}_table`
```

However, creating tables based on user names is never a good idea. For example, mySQL's table naming behaviour will differ based on the operating system - table names will be case sensitive on Linux/Unix, and insensitive on Windows. Also, the range of allowed characters will vary from file system to file system.

It's usually vastly better to have one big table with a `username` column.

Also, the method is vulnerable to SQL injection. If you choose to go this route, `$username` needs to be properly sanitized. Note that [neither mysqli nor PDO can deal with table names as parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: Which is why using a wrapper like MySQLi or PDO comes in handy!

Comment: @Tim not really. :) [Neither mysqli nor PDO can parametrize table names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) - another argument not to have dynamic table names in the first place

Comment: Very interesting. I can see why it isn't supported and but why some people want to do it.

Comment: also, each table is a separate file system object and there can only be a certain system dependent number of tables/files open simultaneously -- if you have a lot of users, you will have performance hits each time your app needs to open a new table.